# 'module' object has no attribute 'corrplot'

Tags: python, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.corrplot(rets,annot=False,diag_names=False)
```

I get this error after I call the function above...don't know whats going on

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-33914bef0513> in <module>()
----> 1 sns.corrplot(rets,annot=False,diag_names=False)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'corrplot'
```

Comment: corrplot and symmaplot have been completely removed at this point. This post and reply have a reasonable way to replicate corrplot on your own: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507756/python-seaborn-how-to-replicate-corrplot). But honestly, just dump seaborn and switch to ggplot + rpy2

Answer (score 8):

The `corrplot` function was deprecated in seaborn version v0.6: https://seaborn.github.io/whatsnew.html#other-additions-and-changes:

> The corrplot() and underlying symmatplot() functions have been deprecated in favor of heatmap(), which is much more flexible and robust. These two functions are still available in version 0.6, but they will be removed in a future version.

Note that the function actually still exists in the seaborn codebase, but you have to directly import it from `seaborn.linearmodels` and you will get a warning that it is subject to removal in a future release.

Comment: corrplot is no longer part of the seaborn code base

Answer (score 2):

Import using the command for corrplot and symmatplot

```
from seaborn.linearmodels import corrplot,symmatplot
```

Comment: The `linearmodels` module has been renamed `regression`. So, if     `from seaborn.regression import corrplot`     wil be used, it throws out: `ImportError: cannot import name 'corrplot'`

Answer (score 1):

***corrplot*** or **symmatplot** has been deprecated in favor of ***heatmap*** .

```
#Example usage
>>> import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
>>> import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
>>> data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
>>> ax = sns.heatmap(data)
```

Check this for more about heatmap: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html#seaborn.heatmap