# Alternative to corrplot() and what input should I use?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.corrplot(rets,annot=False,diag_names=False)
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'corrplot'
```

I tried using the `heatmap()` but was struggling with how to input it.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40059642/module-object-has-no-attribute-corrplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Seaborn: how to replicate corrplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507756/python-seaborn-how-to-replicate-corrplot)